# MUI not load custom variant at first page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I created custom button variant and added custom stylings, the problem is that when page is loading first time custom styling not applying. Stylings applying only when page is refreshed.
I had applied custom variants to `Next.js` projects, but this time I'm adding to `React.js` project without success

**materialTheme.ts**

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material'
import { systemColors, systemStylingSettings } from '../globalVariables'

declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  interface ButtonPropsVariantOverrides {
    containedRed: true
  }
}

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    //   Buttons
    MuiButton: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'containedRed' },
          style: {
            backgroundColor: systemColors.orange,
            borderRadius: systemStylingSettings.borderRadius,
            boxShadow: 'none',
            color: '#ffffff !important',
            '&:hover': {
              backgroundColor: systemColors.orangeDark,
              boxShadow: 'none'
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})

export default theme
```

**index.js**

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.scss'
import App from './App'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'
import './i18n'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/store'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { SnackbarProvider } from 'notistack'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material'
import theme from './styles/materialTheme.ts'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Suspense fallback='Loading'>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={10}>
            <App />
          </SnackbarProvider>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </Suspense>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
serviceWorker.unregister()
```

**jobs.tsx**

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material'
import React from 'react'

const Jobs = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        {/* Create new job button */}
        <Button variant='containedRed'>Custom style button</Button>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Jobs
```